# I need help determining if the current date is before a day of the week and if the target date will fall after a specific day

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Given a date string (2019-05-03 17:56:00) I need to find if the current date is before 5pm on a Tuesday and if the target date (above) is before the next Wednesday.  I hope that isn't confusing.

I thought about just taking the day of the week and comparing today and the target, but then I realized that ahs some logic blocks inherent in it.

We have a jenkins pipeline creating a service now change and our normal changes have to go through CAB.  CAB meetings are on wednesdays with a change deadline of the night before.  If someone runs a job that is targeted for Monday, but today is Wednesday, they will obviously miss the CAB process.  I am using SimpleDateFormat to parse the date.

I'm having an issue testing this logically:
    if ( today > tuesday and target < next wednesday){
        FAIL
    }

Comment: it's not clear what's your problem - calculate next Wednesday?

Comment: I think this boils down to the range between now and the passed in date must totally cover a Tuesday 5pm to Wednesday 5pm 

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what is being asked, but let me give you some Groovy building blocks that will hopefully allow you to write the logic you need. All snippets below require the script to `import java.time.*`

*Is it before 5pm?*

```
boolean isBefore5pm = LocalTime.now().hour <= 17
```

*Is it Tuesday?*

```
boolean isTuesday = LocalDate.now().dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY
```

Perhaps doing some combination of the above will help you determine an answer to your first question. As for the second part.

*What date is next Wednesday?*

Given this general purpose function that takes a day-of-the-week and returns the next date that falls on that day...

```
LocalDate nextDayOfWeekFrom(LocalDate date, DayOfWeek dow) {
    int daysTil = dow.value - date.dayOfWeek.value
    date + (daysTil + (daysTil <= 0 ? 7 : 0))
}
```

...you can determine next Wednesday by calling

```
def nextWednesday = nextDayOfWeekFrom(LocalDate.now(), DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY)
```

*When is the next CAB deadline?*

```
def cabDeadline = LocalDateTime.of(nextDayOfWeekFrom(LocalDate.now(), DayOfWeek.TUESDAY), 
                                   LocalTime.of(17, 0))
```

Hope this helps.